# Como exibir meu template index.html no django restframework?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Estou com um problema em um teste que tenho que entregar para um processo seletivo que estou realizando. Já tentei de todas as formas possíveis e imagináveis resolver mas não consegui. Ao tentar chamar um arquivo index.html que esta dentro de uma pasta templates/api para que ela se torne a raiz da url (http://127.0.0.1:8000) o django não a reconhece.
Segue códigos:

Arquivo urls.py da minha pasta sisquestoes(raiz , pasta que possue o setings.py):
PS: já mudei o nome desta api e mesmo assim não localiza o template .

```
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('api.urls','app_name')),
]
```

Arquivo urls.py da pasta api(que possue a pasta admin.py e os arquivos e templates/api/index.html):

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('questoes', views.QuestoesView)
router.register('user', views.UserView)

app_name="api"
urlpatterns = [
path('', include(router.urls)),
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Funçao na views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from . import views

  def index(request):
      return render(request,'api/index.html')
```

Sinceramente passei a madrugada toda tentando resolver lida praticamente toda documentação, fui por vários caminhos e tutoriais e nada. Fico no aguardo de alguma alma solidária e querida. Grande Abraço.

Comment: Se usa o rest framework , pra que renderizar um índex? Será que faz sentido? Idealmente deveria servir uma api restful. Renderizar html não deveria ser responsabilidade do rest framework, essa é minha opinião. Se pudesse explicar melhor o caso de uso.

Answer (score -1):

O padrão para se incluir urls no Django mudou na versão 2.0
Não é mais utilizado o **url**, e sim o **path**.

Com esta mudança, também não é mais utilizado o regex para definir uma url (pelo menos não com o **path**).

Portanto:

```
# Raiz
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('api.urls')),
    # url(r'^', include('api.urls','app_name')),
]


#views.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('questoes', views.QuestoesView)
router.register('user', views.UserView)

app_name="api"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    # url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Lembrando que a estrutura da pasta onde está o index.html deve ser
**raiz/api/templates/api/index.html**.